# How to handle float numbers using regular expression in VB Script

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am trying to get number with submatches in below string and i am not sure how to handle if my string contains either integer(without decimal) or float number

please correct me where i am making mistake in below code.

```
str="Added Quantity:12.23 Pass"

Set oReg=New RegExp
oReg.pattern="(.*Quantity.*)+((\d{1,})|(\d{1,}\.\d{1,}))(.*)"

set r=oReg.execute(str)

for i=0 to r.count-1
  print r.item(1).submatches(i)
next
```

Comment: You need `oReg.pattern="(.*\bQuantity:)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(.*)"` and get the first `Submatches`. Like `Set rMatch = oReg.Execute(str)` and then `print r(0).SubMatches(1)`

Answer (score 2):

Your expression will *match* numbers alright, but it won’t match in the wrong place. To see why, let’s just consider what `(Quantity.*)(\d{1,})` matches in the following string:

```
Quantity:12.23
```

[Here’s the result of that match:](https://regex101.com/r/zC3zR7/1)

- Whole match: `Quantity:12`

  - Group 1: `Quantity:1`
  - Group 2: `2`

— The problem is that `.*` is *greedy* and matches as much as possible, including digits. It then backtracks so that it can match at least one digit (`\d{1,}`) in its second group. But you want to get *all* digits in there.

Several ways exist to solve this, but the easiest is to make your expression more specific: instead of everything (`.`), just match non-digits:

```
(.*Quantity\D*)+(\d{1,})
```

Furthermore, you don’t need the `+` quantifier here, and `\d{1,}` can be shortened to `\d+`. And in the rest of the expression you can join matching integers and decimals together, and just make the decimal part optional:

```
.*Quantity\D*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*
```

(`(?:…)` just means that this group will not be captured; [the parentheses are merely to enforce operator precedence](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).)

Finally, note this will match `1` and `0.23`, but not `1.`, nor `.23`. While this is completely fine, it’s somewhat common (especially in American spelling) to omit a leading zero in front of the decimal point.